# Xamarin Android SDK Location

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to find out about some logic as to why/where the android SDK items are being picked up.

1. Installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 as my old hard drive died.
2. I installed Visual Studio + Xamarin
3. I have installed Android API 24 + 23
4. Started new project

Get an error saying that Xamarin cannot find Android SDK API 24 android.jar even though the following file exists (where Xamarin Android SDK manager installed it):

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-24\android.jar"`

Although investigating the message further, I found that it is looking for a folder called

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-N\android.jar"`

so I copied + renamed the folder and it seems to be working.

I would like to understand where is it picking up the specific sub platform paths from so I can debug fix these issues easier.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio options include a Xamarin section after Xamarin install, where these settings can be found and modified:

[image]

Comment: I found those setings already, they were correct. I can see my SDK location points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\`but was wondering how it decides that API 25 = `\platform\android-N`rather than `platform\android-25`. Anyway it looked like something was seriously corrupted with my profile/vs/xamarin. I re-installed windows again and it's working fine now :-D

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant by "sub-platform". You've got me curious too if these are magic locations or specified somewhere. I'll post another comment if I stumble across something.